# Apache2 with multiple sites and default

Tags: web-hosting

I am tinkering with an apache2 webserver. I have several sites setup using domain names, however if I just browse to the IP address of the webserver, I get one of the domains I already have setup. I can see letsencrypt forcing https when browsing to the correct domain, but just browsing via IP goes to the non-secure version of that same website. My goal is to land people that browse to it via IP to a certain page (say a block page or something custom) whereas domain name browsers get the correct page. Any ideas on where this is defined?

Robert

Comment: Please check the following answer on ServerFault:
https://serverfault.com/questions/842497/disable-direct-ip-access-in-apache